# Post Request with forms (and JavaScript fetch())

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, fetch, deno

How can i send a form parameter in a post (JavaScript fetch()) request?
e.g.
`curl --form "avatar=@me.jpg" "https://example.com/api/v4/endpoint"`

I tried the folloing code:

```
const form = new FormData()
form.append("foo":"bar")
fetch( "https://someapi.org/api", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers:form
} )
    .then( response => response.json() )
    .then( response => {
        console.log(response)
    } );
}
```

which doesn't work for me.

Comment: You probably want to use the `FormData` instance in `body` and not `headers`

Comment: @Phillip I already tried it but in the Node-API of the api i'm using it's in the headers using form.getHeaders() which doesn't exist in Deno/Web

Answer (score 1):

The `FormData` should be supplied as the `body` property of the `RequestInit`, like this:

> Make sure you use the correct `Content-Type` header. You can read about [Using `FormData` Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) on MDN.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsIwKYA9gC2ADgDbYwAUAlDAN4CwAUDDFJiMvOgE4EwC8MCNgDuMAGI8CAEWDJg1ANxMWcKQDpgRItggATCgCI16QwBoYhgEbBuhqssYrW7TltQBBPXu7YQIAUsAC2RkIhAALgB6KJB0Amx3dR4Acyj3Q0dnNggOGFQIVGQImAAlbABHBD9kAElCzkEGZhYYBOQg9D0SgHIABQB5AGUAFR6zZxYgxL1sbkihURgACRm5kAoAbU2enORdZABaZDAdcZgerVJUKDkMCCjcQ5EXw7VeQ4RuMmgu7D0egBdQFUCYtFhWLpgErvAhglgAXyyLRyeV8ICI7HIgmAImARXg2GQUCCFHcXh8fhAFgKRQc2VcMD0cmAgVx+M46MxuWw6gAVnEIEoGbl0GR1CR0CkKMz5PTGAimEwYjB6gA3dAAa3IRSYeEIpGwSiAA)

`so-70865955.ts`:

```ts
async function example () {
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append("foo", "bar");

  const apiAddress = "https://someapi.org/api";

  const init: RequestInit = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers([['content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded']]),
    body: form,
  };

  const response = await fetch(apiAddress, init);
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data);
}

// Invoke it
example();
```

In your console:

```
deno run --allow-net so-70865955.ts
```

Comment: Hmm, i'm trying to use the neocities API (https://neocities.org/api), here's how the dev did it in node: https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/aebdcc54ea7246828f3ba1be3cacfbf5

Comment: @ProgrammerDevelopement I wrote a Neocities client for you: https://deno.land/x/neocities

Comment: Uh, nice! Thanks a lot!